# local.xml not working

Tags: configuration, local.xml, design

I'm new to Magento, previously used osCommerce. I'm trying to use Magento with Bootstrap. Followed all the instructions, i'm testing the local.xml file. Following is the code i'm using in local.xml to test website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <default module="page" translate="label">
      <reference name="head">
         <!-- Adding Javascripts -->
         <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.min.js</name>
         </action>
         <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/bootstrap.min.js</name>
         </action>
         <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.scripts.js</name>
         </action>
         <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/html5shiv.js</name>
            <params />
            <if>lt IE 9</if>
         </action>
         <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/respond.min.js</name>
            <params />
            <if>lt IE 9</if>
         </action>
         <!-- Removing the styles.css -->
         <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/styles.css</name>
         </action>
         <!-- Adding Bootstrap Css -->
         <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/bootstrap.min.css</stylesheet>
         </action>
         <!-- Adding the styles.css -->
         <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet>
         </action>
      </reference>
      <!-- // Default -->
      <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
         </action>
      </reference>
      <!-- Left Sidebar -->
      <reference name="left">
         <!-- remove the default newsletter block from the sidebar -->
         <remove name="left.newsletter" />
      </reference>
      <!-- // Left Sidebar -->
   </default>
</layout>
```

When I refresh website nothing happens, the default Madison Island appears with no alteration. Is there something missing or something needs to be done on my part to see changes. Will be grateful for all help.

Comment: Did you add your new package/theme under System > Configuration > Design?

Comment: At what location you saving local.xml?

Answer (score 3):

Fo saving your local.xml file use below path -

```
/app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/local.xml
```

Remember after adding all these stuff -

```
 => Clear Magento Cache
 => Clear Browser Cache
```

Hope, will work for you

Note: {your_package}/{your_theme} same as You have in admin -> system -> design
Note2: try to remove all comments like

> `<!-- Adding Javascripts -->`

in my case them produce parsing errors

Comment: Did you add your new package/theme under System > Configuration > Design? I created package/theme using Cpanel, /app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme   My local.xml is stored at:
/app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/local.xml   My cache has been disabled, i've also cleared magento and browser cache.

Comment: So "mypackage" is something different than {your package} or just a oversight¿